# Passing key to add_query_arg function in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my edit link in template file

```
$edit_link=add_query_arg( 'ser_edit', $post_id, $edit_link ) ;
```

This is my html code.

```
 <a href="<?php  print $edit_link;?>"><?php _e('Edit','wpestate');?></a>
```

When I change first parameter in add_query_arg, It works fine but ser_edit is the correct parameter for that. But it display blank page when I click on edit link in html. I checked console, no error. Anybody has any idea??

It display correct url in browser but display total blank page.
When I change key parameter, it works fine. So how to solve this??

Comment: After adding the query arg, what does `$edit_link` look like?

Comment: @Anand see my edit above

Comment: Have you checked your web server's error logs to see if there's a 500 Internal Server error being thrown? Also try enabling WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php and it may give some more clues.

Comment: No 500 error in error log. wp_debug is already true. Also put error_reporting code in config.php

Comment: When I try browsing to the link you've provided in your post, I get redirected to http://plotsup.com/plotsup_plot/url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this**

**if you want to pass single value in query arg**

```
add_query_arg( 'ser_edit',$post_id,get_permalink() ) ;
```

**And if you want to pass multiple value in query arg**

```
add_query_arg(array('arg1'=>'value1','arg2'=>'value2'), get_permalink());
```

Comment: I have problem with ser_edit i.e key in add_query_arg. When I change it to another, it works fine. But ser_edit is correct key for that.