# how to save multiple checkboxes value in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my code for checkboxes.

```
<p class="full_form"><label for="prop_category"><?php _e('We are into','wpestate');?></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="architecture" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="architecture" >Architecture
        <input type="checkbox" id="builder_developer" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="builder_developer">Builders and Developeres
        <input type="checkbox" id="material_supplier" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="material_supplier">Material Supplier
        <input type="checkbox" id="contractor" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="contractor">Contractor
        <input type="checkbox" id="int_decorator" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="int_decorator">Interior Decorator
        <input type="checkbox" id="prop_finance" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="prop_finance">Property Finance
        <input type="checkbox" id="prop_legal_ad" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="prop_legal_ad">Property Legal Advisor
        <input type="checkbox" id="prop_valuer" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="prop_valuer">Property Valuer
        <input type="checkbox" id="vastu_consult" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="vastu_consult">Vaastu Consultant
```

How Do I save multiple checkboxes  in wordpress postmeta table? Should I save them as array? How Do I access them after form submit? And how do I display selected checkbox value while editing??

Comment: many  way to do this please add some code or information of your code

Comment: google it to find a lot of answers

Comment: googled it but dont get answer according to my need.

Comment: @Rasel No need to be so harsh, this community is here to awnser questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**try this way** 
**Html code**

```
<p class="full_form"><label for="prop_category">We are into</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="architecture" size="80" name="service_name[]"  value="Architecture" >Architecture
            <input type="checkbox" id="builder_developer" size="80" name="service_name[]"  value="Builders and Developeres">Builders and Developeres
            <input type="checkbox" id="material_supplier" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="Material Supplier">Material Supplier
            <input type="checkbox" id="contractor" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="Contractor">Contractor
            <input type="checkbox" id="int_decorator" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="Interior Decorator">Interior Decorator
            <input type="checkbox" id="prop_finance" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="Property Finance">Property Finance
            <input type="checkbox" id="prop_legal_ad" size="80" name="service_name[]"  value="Property Legal Advisor">Property Legal Advisor
            <input type="checkbox" id="prop_valuer" size="80" name="service_name[]"  value="Property Valuer">Property Valuer
            <input type="checkbox" id="vastu_consult" size="80" name="service_name[]" value="Vaastu Consultant">Vaastu Consultant
```

**Submit code for save**

```
<?php 
        //submit code 
          if(isset($_POST['service_name'])  ){
              $data=serialize($_POST['service_name']);

              update_post_meta($postid, 'service_name', $data);
          }
        ?>
```

**Edit code**

```
<?php 
        //edit code

            $data=get_post_meta($postid, 'service_name');
            //$data=unserialize($data[0]);
            $data=$data[0];
            print_r($data);

        ?> 

        <input type="checkbox" id="architecture" size="80" name="service_name[]"  value="Architecture" <?php if(in_array('Architecture',$data)  ){echo "checked";} ?> >Architecture



//other checkbox put as this
```

in_array [check it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: I giving me ..Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument

Comment: in_array support first arg ad value you check in array and second arg as array variable . check your second argument variable is array or not?

Comment: Data saved in serialize format. Save code working fine but at the time of edit I am not able to get it as an array and second arg is not an array.

Comment: in edit you get serialize data am i right? first you get serialize data then used  "unserialize()" function (it's convert data in array)

Comment: I m not getting anything in $data.

Comment: Sry, It's not your fault. I am not getting post_id  there.

Comment: Please see this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750467/passing-key-to-add-query-arg-function-in-wordpress"... And tell me solution.

Comment: hi Now I am getting $data as array and also post_id. But error is  unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: replace this  $data=unserialize($data[0]); to  $data=$data[0]; and try

Comment: @Ankur Bhadania, Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given